# Streaming audio using Python (without GStreamer)

Tags: python, audio, stream, pygame, playback

I'm working on a project that involves streaming .OGG (or .mp3) files from my webserver.  I'd prefer not to have to download the whole file and then play it, is there a way to do that in pure Python (no GStreamer - hoping to make it truly cross platform)?  Is there a way to use urllib to download the file chunks at a time and load that into, say, PyGame to do the actual audio playing?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm in a similar corner. I'm trying to see if I can transform an audio file into base-64 chunks to be sent over a network to be re-converted and played by the client

Comment: I heard that GStreamer is cross-platform: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your server supports **Range requests**. You ask the server by header *Range* with start byte and end byte of the range you want:

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (startByte, endByte)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)

f.read()
```

You can implement a [file object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) and always download just a needed chunk of file from server. Almost every library accepts  a file object as input.

It will be probably slow because of a network latency. You would need to download bigger chunks of the file, preload the file in a separate thread, etc. In other words, you would need to implement the streaming client logic yourself.

Comment: how to play that chunks