# how to play a audio from a url while downloading- using python

Tags: python, http, networking, audio, streaming

I want to write a python script that plays a audio from the given url,
I know it can be simply done by downloading the full audio at the start and play it, but I want to play the audio at the same time of download the chunks by using something like stream=True in python requests library
but I don't want to use python-vlc library

I tried pyaudio library but it simply make buzz.. buzz sounds then I use pygame like this:

```
import requests
from pygame import mixer 

def stream_remote_audio(url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    
    for i in r.iter_content(1024):
        
        # Starting the mixer 
        mixer.init() 
        
        with open("m.mp3","wb") as d:
            d.write(i)
        # Loading the song 
        mixer.music.load("m.mp3") 
        
        # Setting the volume 
        mixer.music.set_volume(0.7) 
        
        # Start playing the song 
        mixer.music.play()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    audio_url = "audio url"
    stream_remote_audio(audio_url)
```

but it makes errors:

```
music_drmp3: corrupt mp3 file (bad stream).
```

is there any library for doing it other than python-vlc

Comment: just speculating, but how about using a named pipe? Or create the mixer once and queue files?

Comment: You shouldn't be opening the file every iteration of the for loop.  Open it once, then  call `d.write(i)` in the for loop.   The file won't contain all the data until the for loop ends, so you can't use `mixer.music.load("m.mp3")` within the for loop as you're still writing to that file.  If you can stream mp3 content into `mixer.music`, you'll probably do so by writing it to a buffer and telling `mixer.music` to stream from that buffer.  I don't know anything about pygame itself but I didn't see an interface for `mixer.music` that loads from a stream

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115022/streaming-audio-using-python-without-gstreamer

Comment: how to play that chunks